Direct I/O in kernel space fails
For some specific reasons, I'm managing to read file directly from disk (i.e., bypassing the page cache) in a x64 Linux kernel (v5.4.0).
In user space, this can be done by passing the the O_DIRECT flag to open(). Here is my user space code (and it works fine):
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open(fpath, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT); // fpath is the path to the file to be read
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    struct stat fstat;
    stat(fpath, &fstat); 
    int blksize = (int)fstat.st_blksize;
    int align = blksize-1;

    const char *big_buf = (char *) malloc(blksize + align);
    
    unsigned char *buff = (char *)( (unsigned long)(big_buf+align) & ~align );

    if(read(fd, buff, (size_t)blksize) < 1) 
    { 
            //Error handling
            free(big_buf);
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


To achieve the same goal in kernel space, I've read this question. In my understanding, there are 2 constraints for vfs_read() to work properly:

buffer should come from user space
buffer should be aligned to block size

I have tried to use the following code to compile a kernel module(assuming the block size is 0x1000, in my user space code, 0x1000 works fine):
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/uio.h>

static int __init start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO, "module installed\n");

    struct file *fp = filp_open("/home/chibigwen/Desktop/ko/nonsense", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT, 0);
    int rv;
    mm_segment_t old_fs;
    old_fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    
    if (IS_ERR(fp)) {
        printk("filp_open() failed\n");
        rv = PTR_ERR(fp);
    }
    else 
    {
        loff_t pos = 0;

        unsigned char *big_buf = kmalloc(0x2000, GFP_KERNEL);

        if(big_buf == NULL)
        {
            printk("bad kmalloc\n");
        }

        // it seems like we don't need alignment
        unsigned char *kread_buf = (unsigned char *)((unsigned long)(big_buf + 0xfff) & ~0xfff);

        rv = kernel_read(fp, kread_buf, 0x1000, &pos);
        
        if (rv < 0)
        {
            printk("bad kernel_read(), rv: %d\n", rv);
        }
        else
        {
            printk("kernel_read() reads %d bytes\n", rv);
            printk("on disk: %x %x %x\n", kread_buf[0x100], kread_buf[0x101], kread_buf[0x102]);
        }

        kfree(big_buf);
    }
    filp_close(fp, NULL);
    set_fs(old_fs);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO, "module uninstalled\n");
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(end);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Chibi Gwen");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A module to test Direct I/O");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");


In my code, I think the aforementioned 2 constraints are already satisfied. However, kernel_read() still returns -EFAULT. If I remove the O_DIRECT flag, kernel_read() successfully returns.
Any help or suggestions are welocomed and greatly appreciated!
